# R: Subsetting Time Series

Tags: r

I have this time series data in R:

```
# Generate weekly sales time series from 2000-01-01 to 2020-01-01
set.seed(123)
sales <- ts(rnorm(1040, mean = 100, sd = 50), start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 52)
```

**My Question:** I want to split this time series into two parts: before 2010-01-01 and after 2010-01-01

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
# Split the time series before and after January 1, 2010
before <- window(sales, end = as.Date("2009-12-31"))
after <- window(sales, start = as.Date("2010-01-01"))

# Plot the two time series with a vertical line at January 1, 2010
plot(before, main = "Weekly Sales Before/After Jan 1, 2010", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Sales", col = "blue")
lines(after, col = "red")
abline(v = as.numeric(as.Date("2010-01-01")), lty = "dotted", lwd = 2, col = "green")
legend("topleft", legend = c("Before Jan 1, 2010", "After Jan 1, 2010"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = 1)
```

**My Problem:** But I get the following error: `Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'`

I thought of an alternate way to address this problem - there are 1040 observations, so I could manually just select before and after the halfway point:

```
before <- ts(sales[1:520], start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 52)
after <- ts(sales[21:1040],start = c(2010, 1), frequency = 52)
```

But can someone please show me a more direct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`window` expects its `start` and `end` arguments to be specified as documented in `?ts`, *not* as objects of class `Date`:

```r
before <- window(sales, end = c(2009, 52))
after <- window(sales, start = c(2010, 1))
```